# Does EAV datamodels considered as advanced form of database normalization?

Tags: database, normalization

i am confused when looking at databases designed with the [EAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-attribute-value_model) concept. EAV stands for entity, attribute and value. my question is: Does EAV datamodels considered as advanced form of database normalization ? is it a "must use" to be "up to date" ?

to cut long things short: when to use EAV and when not?

Comment: The only time you should consider EAV is if you **absolutely can't** know the full schema up front.  That does **NOT** include cases where you are too lazy to do a full analysis of the schema requirements.

Comment: Doesn't seem like this is related to ASP.NET.  If that's the case, please consider removing the "ASP.NET" tag from this question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, they are considered to be an anti-pattern.

They can be seen as taking normalization to an absurd level (I have seen people think that this is a good idea), causing one to lose all notion of easy ad-hock querying and causing havoc with the notion of proper indexing.

EAV has a place when you have no idea what the schema will be (say for a client customizable "database").

Comment: what do u mean by "anti-pattern"?

Comment: Is it a "must use" in " modern" database design

Comment: @mokokamello - I mean they are considered to be a **bad thing** ™. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern

Comment: @mokokamello - It is an - avoid unless you really know what you are doing and have thought very carefully about it.

Comment: @Oded. Agree with the anti-pattern comment. It's not right that EAV is "taking normalization to an absurd level" though. EAV has nothing to do with normalization. Don't taint normalization by suggesting that it does.

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule of thumb, EAV models are not good design practices, and should be avoided in most cases.  However, there may be cases where they are the best solution for the problem at hand, but it should be rare.

Your database toolbox should include a variety of tools, some of which are much more specialized than others.  The EAV shouldn't be a hammer or a screwdriver, but more like a sledgehammer; you can drive nails with it, but it's not very effective in the long run.